# Graphviz, changing the size of edge

Tags: graphviz, dot

How to change the size of edge in dot (graphviz)?
I would like to make some edges "bolded".

Answer (score 163, accepted):

I wanted to supplement shuvalov's answer. ***penwidth*** is indeed the correct command. Additionally, in shuvalov's answer *penwidth* is *both* a node and an edge property--also correct.

The distinction i wanted to make:

- *penwidth*, when used as a node
  property (e.g., "NodeA" [penwidth =
  5]) affects the border line weight
  for that node
- *penwidth*, when used as a edge
  property affects the line weight of
  the edge (default value is "1",
  specifying penwidth=2 will make the
  edge appear in **bold** type
- if you want to change the line weight
  of an edge, you do not need to change
  *penwidth* for the two nodes
  connected by that edge (as shuvalev's
  answer might suggest)
- for a *directed graph* (the edges have
  a direction) you might also wish to change the
  size/weight of the *arrowhead* and
  *arrowtail*, along with the *edge
  weight*, so that all three remain
  proportional
- the *length* of an edge can be changed
  by setting the *weight* property, as
  elsewhere, the default value is 1.0;
  increasing that value increases the
  cost of stretching this edge during
  rendering (i.e., the drawing
  algorithm applies a higher penalty to
  solutions in which this edge is
  longer); notice that the edge from 1
  to 4 is shorter than the edge from 1
  to 2.

The following code should illustrate all of this. The rendered graph is shown below the code.

```
digraph {
    /* declare the node & style them */
    "Node 1" [shape=diamond, penwidth=3, style=filled, fillcolor="#FCD975"];
    "Node 2" [style=filled,fillcolor="#9ACEEB" ];
    "Node 3" [shape=diamond, style=filled, fillcolor="#FCD975" ];
    "Node 4" [style=filled, fillcolor="#9ACEEB" ]

    /* declare the edges & style them */
    "Node 1" -> "Node 2" [dir=none, weight=1, penwidth=3] ;
    "Node 1" -> "Node 3" [dir=none, color="#9ACEEB"] ;
    "Node 1" -> "Node 4" [arrowsize=.5, weight=2.]
}
```

[image]

Comment: For some reason the `weight` property isn't changing anything for me. The rest is super helpful, though…thanks!

Comment: This was very helpful, in particular with the image - helped me understand the relationship here. The graphviz syntax is a bit peculiar, so such nice images really helped a lot. The only part, if I would change in the above, would be to add a bit more of an explanation in regards to penwidth, because right now the lines are all bold (I changed that, thanks to the above), but the border around the individual nodes are not thicker, which I initially wanted to do. I may get to solve this problem eventually, but in the event that I forget to publish the solution here, I just add this instead. :)

Answer (score 31):

try this:

```
"NodeA" [ penwidth = 5]
"NodeB" [ penwidth = 5]
NodeA->NodeB [ penwidth = 3]
```

Comment: Other answer containing much more details and is greatly explained, but this one is much more simple, and so can be read and understand faster! It should be the research engine preview.