# How do I make a force-directed graph in python?

Tags: python, data-visualization, igraph, networkx, r-qgraph

I want a graph that shows a few nodes, directional arrows between nodes representing a relationship, with thickness relative to the strength of their connection.

In R this is very simple

```
library("qgraph")
test_edges <- data.frame(
   from = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'),
   to = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'c'),
   thickness = c(1,5,2,2,1))
qgraph(test_edges, esize=10, gray=TRUE)
```

Which produces:
[image: force directed graph via R]

But in Python I haven't been able to find a clear example. NetworkX and igraph seem to hint that it's possible, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 8):

I first tried doing this with NetworkX's standard drawing functions, which use matplotlib, but I was not very successful.

However, NetworkX also [supports drawing to the `dot` format](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/reference/drawing.html#module-networkx.drawing.nx_agraph), which [supports edge weight, as the `penwidth` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2363990/539465).

So here is a solution:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph()
edges = [
    ('a', 'a', 1),
    ('a', 'b', 5),
    ('a', 'c', 2),
    ('b', 'a', 2),
    ('b', 'c', 1),
    ]
for (u, v, w) in edges:
    G.add_edge(u, v, penwidth=w)

nx.nx_pydot.write_dot(G, '/tmp/graph.dot')
```

Then, to show the graph, run in a terminal:

```
dot -Tpng /tmp/graph.dot > /tmp/graph.png
xdg-open /tmp/graph.png
```

(or the equivalent on your OS)

Which shows:

[image: output of the graph described by OP]