# Can't set weight for graph with networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx

Can't set weight for edges in graph.
My dataset

[image]

```
    dict_value={'Источник':[10301.0,10301.0,10301.0,10301.0,10329.0,10332.0,10333.0,10334.0,174143.0,1030408.0,10306066.0],  'Собеседник':[300.0,315.0,343.0,344.0,300.0,300.0,300.0,300.0,300.0,300.0,300.0],
'Частота':[164975000,164975000,164437500,164975000,164975000,164975000,164975000,164975000,164975000,164975000,164975000],
        'БС LAC':[9,9,1,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9],
        'Длительность':[20,3,2,2,3,3,2,3,3,3,3]}
session_graph=pd.DataFrame(dict_value)
```

My code:

```
G = nx.MultiDiGraph() 
for row in session_graph.itertuples():
    if row[4]==1:
       G.add_edge(row[1], row[2],label=row[3],color="green",weight=0.9)
    if row[4]==9:
       G.add_edge(row[1], row[2],label=row[3],color="red",weight=0.4)
p=nx.drawing.nx_pydot.to_pydot(G)
p.write_png('multi.png')
Image(filename='multi.png')
```

[image]

Weight don't change! What I do wrong?Con you help me?

Comment: Can you share a sample of the dataframe instead of an image?

Comment: @yatu, I add dataframe.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of [your another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64317124/5260876). Consider removing one of the questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change edge thickness, add `penwidth` to your arguments

```py
G = nx.MultiDiGraph() 
for row in session_graph.itertuples():
    if row[4]==1:
       G.add_edge(row[1], row[2],label=row[3],color="green",weight=0.9, penwidth = 5)
    if row[4]==9:
       G.add_edge(row[1], row[2],label=row[3],color="red",weight=0.4, penwidth = 1)
```

If you draw your graph in `dot` format with you will see, that the problem is in GraphViz - it ignores weight argument but works with `penwidth` parameter, so you need to pass it to the drawing library.
See [Graphviz, changing the size of edge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2363990/5260876) question for details.

[image: resulting graph]

Comment: thank you. The problem is that when the graph is output, the connection lines are all of the same thickness, as I understand the weight value changes its thickness.

Comment: Replied to your comment at the answer. Please write that you want to change edge thickness to the question body.