# Adding color gradient in graphviz edges

Tags: graphviz, dot

From the example given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333025/graphviz-changing-the-size-of-edge), I can change edge width using `weight`/`penwidth`.

I can add color using `color`.

Now, how to put gradient? Is this even possible for an edge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seemingly not.  If you read here: https://graphviz.org/docs/attr-types/colorList/ and here: https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/color/, you will find that gradients are possible, but not for edges.  Instead of a gradient, you get parallel colored lines.

> For edges, the value can either be a single color or a colorList.
>
> In the latter case, if colorList has no fractions, the edge is drawn
> using parallel splines or lines, one for each color in the list, in
> the order given.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, the question has no solution.